# Identifying old single handle shower valve/cartride?

Tags: shower, leak, faucet, bathtub, cartridge

Need help identifying the tub/shower faucet valve/cartridge in the pictures below.  I shutoff the main and removed EVERYTHING in preparation for replacement at a later date, and realized I never took a picture of the actual CARTRIDGE itself, and want to see if I can get some experienced eyes to help identify a couple parts!  (The issue we're fixing is a LEAKING tub faucet.)

I want to replace the cartridge/stem all together if possible -- but if that's too hard to identify, I took a picture of the washers in the valve as well -- hoping I can simply replace those for both hot/cold water sides.  I was expecting washers/springs but this what I found when I opened up and I've never seen these before!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What did the handle look like? Also, there are no markings not already shown in the above pictures?

Answer (score 3):

Looks similar to mine.
"Price Pfister, the Pfabulous Pfaucet with the Pfunny name".
Web search for Pfister Style 974-491 should yield multiple purchasing options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have several plumbing catalogs and have searched them thoroughly. I cannot locate any replacement compression rings/washers that look similar to those. I did locate a pressure balance cartridge that looks very similar to the one you have.

[**American Standard Reliant + Pressure Balance Cartridge**](https://www.americanstandard-us.com/parts-support/parts/bathtub-parts/bath-shower-faucet-parts/reliant-bathshower-pressure-balance-cartridge-15547)
[image]

Here is a parts diagram for an American Standard R110, which I believe is the Reliant 110. If you look at the face plate, the setup looks similar to yours, with the exception that it doesn't say American Standard. American Standard has two models of pressure balance cartridges that look very similar and they both fit several different models. I would buy one of each model and send the one back that doesn't fit. You can also send those pictures to [**customer support at American Standard**](https://www.americanstandard-us.com/parts-support/contact-us)

[image]
[image]